# Get access token from google account in dialogflow intent

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net-mvc, firebase, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Google account linking process is completed and access token is generated and stored it to the google account.Here, so how do i get google account access token into my application or in dialogflow intent. I have implemented dialogflow intent in node Js and hosted it on firebase.

Receive an access token in my application which has stored in google account.

Comment: please share what have to tried so far to get access token

Comment: I am completely blank about this process so just referred below mentioned link https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in